# SQL IN command but not for any of the values that match, but must match all values

Tags: sql

The SQL IN command allows you to find values that match any of the specified values in a WHERE clause. For example:

```
WHERE Keywords IN ('Blue', 'Green', 'Red');
```

would give you results that contain any of those keywords. What if I want to return only those rows that have ALL of those keywords? So if only 'Blue' was in keywords but not 'Red' it would not be included.

Comment: A column's value can't be 'Blue' and 'Green' in the same row. Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
where lower(keyword) like '%red%'
and lower(keyword) like '%blue%'
and lower(keyword) like '%green%'
```

Comment: The `lower()` is not needed when your database is CASE INSENSITIVE